# JPA2 One-to-many serialization exception

Tags: hibernate, glassfish, ejb-3.0, jpa-2.0

I have such a problem when migrating from Hibernate to JPA2 in new EJB project.

In stateless bean i fetching a parent class instance which name is ProductType with unidirectional One-to-many relationship of TypeItems. It perfectly extracted from database, i saw it in server logs, but when I return ProductType entity from stateless bean method, client suddenly crashes with exception. Ok. At firsh i brake this relationship and each part of them succesfully passed from server to client. Late I made a fake method which produces such structure, but not taken from database... and it works!

I really have no idea why fetched from database entities with One-to-many relationship break my system down.
BTW. I use glassfish 3.1.1 and hibernate 3.5.0 as persistence provider.

Now a little bit of code. I'll skip getters and setters for primitves.
This is parent class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_types")
@XmlRootElement
public class ProductType implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "type_id")
    private Integer typeId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "type_name")
    private String typeName;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="type_id")
    private Set<TypeItem> typeItems = new HashSet<TypeItem>();


    public Set<TypeItem> getTypeItems() {
        return typeItems;
    }


    public void setTypeItems(Set<TypeItem> items) {
        this.typeItems = new HashSet<TypeItem>(items);
    }
}
```

and the TypeItem(bad name btw)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "types_list")
@XmlRootElement
public class TypeItem implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "type_name")
    private String typeName;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "type_translation")
    private String typeTranslation;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "type_var")
    private String typeVar;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "type_measure")
    private String typeMeasure;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "type_id")
    private int typeId;
```

}

and the exception is:

```
10.11.2011 21:52:45 com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator handleFullLogging
WARNING: IOP00810011: Exception from readValue on ValueHandler in CDRInputStream
org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: WARNING: IOP00810011: Exception from readValue on ValueHandler in CDRInputStream  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 11 completed: Maybe
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:248)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:95)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.handleFullLogging(WrapperGenerator.java:387)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.access$400(WrapperGenerator.java:107)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator$2.invoke(WrapperGenerator.java:511)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.proxy.CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.java:99)
    at $Proxy24.valuehandlerReadException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1022)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1123)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:531)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl$14.read(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:384)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.readResult(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:483)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:203)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:152)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.codegen.CodegenStubBase.invoke(CodegenStubBase.java:227)
    at hameleon.session.productmanagement.__ProductTypeManagerRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.getProductType(hameleon/session/productmanagement/__ProductTypeManagerRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.java)
    at hameleon.session.productmanagement._ProductTypeManagerRemote_Wrapper.getProductType(hameleon/session/productmanagement/_ProductTypeManagerRemote_Wrapper.java)
    at hameleonclient.HameleonClient.main(HameleonClient.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.ClassInfoCache$ClassInfo.<init>(ClassInfoCache.java:156)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.ClassInfoCache.get(ClassInfoCache.java:281)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1097)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:531)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:2162)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2404)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1224)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:425)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:308)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1015)
    ... 10 more
Exception in thread "main" javax.ejb.EJBException: java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 1330446347 Maybe; nested exception is: 
    org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: WARNING: IOP00810011: Exception from readValue on ValueHandler in CDRInputStream  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 11 completed: Maybe
    at hameleon.session.productmanagement._ProductTypeManagerRemote_Wrapper.getProductType(hameleon/session/productmanagement/_ProductTypeManagerRemote_Wrapper.java)
    at hameleonclient.HameleonClient.main(HameleonClient.java:34)
Caused by: java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 1330446347 Maybe; nested exception is: 
    org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: WARNING: IOP00810011: Exception from readValue on ValueHandler in CDRInputStream  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 11 completed: Maybe
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.mapSystemException(Util.java:267)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:213)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:152)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.codegen.CodegenStubBase.invoke(CodegenStubBase.java:227)
    at hameleon.session.productmanagement.__ProductTypeManagerRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.getProductType(hameleon/session/productmanagement/__ProductTypeManagerRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.java)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: WARNING: IOP00810011: Exception from readValue on ValueHandler in CDRInputStream  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 11 completed: Maybe
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:248)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:95)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.handleFullLogging(WrapperGenerator.java:387)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.access$400(WrapperGenerator.java:107)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator$2.invoke(WrapperGenerator.java:511)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.proxy.CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.java:99)
    at $Proxy24.valuehandlerReadException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1022)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1123)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:531)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl$14.read(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:384)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.readResult(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:483)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:203)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.ClassInfoCache$ClassInfo.<init>(ClassInfoCache.java:156)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.ClassInfoCache.get(ClassInfoCache.java:281)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1097)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:531)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:2162)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2404)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1224)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:425)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:308)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1015)
    ... 10 more
Java Result: 1
```

UPD. I continue my research and copy object returned by entityManager.find() in new object property by property. And it works! Is bug/feature or my personal misunderstood of J2EE?

Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 1):

I got exactly the same error using Hibernate, which maybe is similar in JPA2.

The problem was that my remote client did not included necessary hibernate libraries, which were necessary since hibernate internally casts properties of an entity like Set, Bag to its own Counterparts like PersistentSet.

*One more point to remove hibernate from remotely passed entities, since there should be no need in my remote client to know hibernate at all!*

After searching for two days i found it in this forum:
http://www.guj.com.br/java/251468-resolvido-problema-em-ejb-ao-retornar-objeto-recuperado-do-banco